# How to make git archive in 7zip format?

Tags: git, 7zip

7zip tends to compress a lot better than tar.gz or zip, but `git archive` only supports these two fairly ancient formats.

Is there any simple way of making output of `git archive` compress as 7zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git archive master | xz -z > archived.xz`. Note that `xz` and `7z` use the same compression algorithm. You can then unpack it with `xz -d`.